# Renombrar el conteo de resultados de una relación en Laravel

Tags: eloquent, laravel-7

Necesito poner el equivalente a un 'as' en una subconsulta con un with en un controlador de eloquent ya que necesito obtener propiedades de la misma tabla hija.

```
$userInfo = auth()->user()->id;
    $projects =  Project::withCount(['project_contents' => function($query){
        $query->where('complete', 1);
    }, 'project_images'])
    ->with(['project_images','project_contents'])
    ->where('user_id', $userInfo)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')-get();
```

como se aprecia en el código anterior estoy haciendo dos with ya que necesito obtener las propiedades completas de esas tablas hijas, y además estoy haciendo dos withCount a las mismas tablas para obtener el numero de columnas que pertenecen al proyecto, en la tabla project_contents estoy haciendo haciendo un query para obtener los project_contents que esten completados, pero tambien necesito obtener los project_contents que tengan otra propiedad 'type' que sea igual a 'link'.

Lo que se me ocurrió fue hacer en el mismo withCount algo así:

```
withCount(['project_contents' => function($query){
        $query->where('complete', 1);
    }, 'project_contents'=> function ($query){
            $query->where('type', 'link');}, 'project_images'])
```

pero al obtener los datos de count eloquent no sabe que count debe hacer ya que las dos consultas se dirigen a la misma tabla y en vuejs se llama con el mismo nombre:

```
project.project_contens_count
```

recalcando que en vuejs hice un v-for de projects y llamo a la propiedad project.project_contents_count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De manera predeterminada el nombre del conteo tendrá esta nomenclatura: **`relacion_count`**, que obtenemos cuando hacemos esto:

```
Modelo::withCount('relacion')->get();
```

Sin embargo Eloquent nos permite renombrar el resultado del conteo de la relación de esta forma:

```
Modelo::withCount([
    'usuarios',
    'usuarios as usuarios_activos_conteo',
])->get();
```

Entonces tu segmento de consulta puede quedar así:

```
withCount(['project_contents as projectsA_count' => function($query){
        $query->where('complete', 1);
    }, 'project_contents as projectsB_count'=> function ($query){
            $query->where('type', 'link');}, 'project_images'])
```

- Puedes leer mas al respecto [aquí en la doc.](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models)

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo!!! me funcionó perfectamente... te estaré eternamente agradecido!!!!